# What is the correct syntax for AMD monitorx instruction?

Tags: assembly, syntax-error, x86-64

Ryzen supports the `monitorx` instructions, as indicated by the cpuid flag. Unfortunately the visual studio masm assembler doesn't seem to like these instructions, and there is very little documentation online for how to use them.

The following code (which is very based on AMD's own documentation) reports the error A2070 "invalid instruction operands:

```
push rbx
mov eax, 5844h
mov ecx, 0
mov edx, 0
monitorx eax, ecx, edx
pop rbx
ret
```

I understand that this code isn't very useful, but it shouldn't be throwing build time errors, so what's the deal?

Comment: The operands are implicit. You should just use `monitorx`.

Comment: @Jester that gives error A2008: "syntax error: in instruction"

Comment: It is possible that your copy of the assembler does not support this instruction.  Try manually entering its opcode with `db` directives.

Comment: @fuz it recognizes it, if it didn't the error would be "syntax error: monitorx"

Comment: @Badasahog Makes sense.  Try doing that anyway.  Then, disassemble the resulting binary with Microsoft's disassembler and check what mnemonic is generated.  Use the same syntax.

Comment: Try with the 64 bit registers then.

Comment: @fuz when I do that (with no operands) it shows monitorx rax,rcx,rdx in disassembly (which compiles when put in the assembly file)

Comment: @Jester it should work with 32 bit registers according to the documentation

Comment: Well, in 64 bit mode the address is 64 bits. GNU assembler doesn't accept the 32 bit version either.

Comment: @Jester duh (sorry for wasting your time)

Comment: Do I delete the question?

Comment: @Badasahog No!  Instead, write what you learned up as an answer and post it below your question.  This way further users with the same question can benefit from this wisdom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In machine code, the operands are implicit.  In assembly syntax, plain `monitorx` works for most assemblers.  The operands can be specified to document the instruction, or in some assemblers to specify an override to the address-size.

[AMD's manual](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24594.pdf) explicitly says that ECX and EDX are 32-bit operands.  (They say there are no hints or extensions defined, so ECX must be 0 else #GP, and EDX is ignored by current CPUs.)

For the address operand, they document it as rAX, which I think means it can be EAX or RAX.  In the pseudocode example, they use `MONITORX EAX, ECX, EDX`, but the 32-bit EAX means that's a 32-bit-mode example.

This is in their vol.3 manual, Nov. 2021 rev 3.33, the latest linked from https://developer.amd.com/resources/developer-guides-manuals/.

---

##### NASM 2.15.05  (support added for `monitorx` in [version](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdocc.html) 2.12.01)

The operand list can be specified or omitted.  If specified, the first operand must be EAX or RAX, and the next two *must* be ECX and EDX.  (It's an error to specify RCX or RDX).

But NASM doesn't infer 32-bit address-size in 64-bit mode from using EAX.
Segment overrides can be specified with NASM prefixes.
Example listing from `nasm -l/dev/stdout -felf64 foo.asm`:

```
     1 00000000 0F01FA             monitorx
     2 00000003 0F01FA             monitorx rax, ecx, edx
     3 00000006 0F01FA             monitorx eax, ecx, edx       ; address-size override not inferred from EAX

     4 00000009 670F01FA           a32 monitorx                 ; address-size prefix, NASM style
     5 0000000D 640F01FA           fs monitorx rax, ecx, edx    ; segment override works, too
```

`ndisasm -b64` disassembles it as just `monitorx`, `fs monitorx`, or `a32 monitorx` without listing the implicit operands.  GNU Binutils `objdump` is the same in `-Mintel` syntax mode, but lists operands in AT&T mode.  (Backwards, with `%rax` or `%eax` as the first operand, not reversed like AT&T syntax should be!)

---

YASM is too old, hasn't been updated in years.  I haven't tried FASM.

---

#### GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.36.1

Unlike NASM, GAS does infer the address-size from RAX vs. EAX.  (Or in 32-bit mode, infer 16-bit address size from `monitorx ax, ecx, edx`)

GAS does *not* check sizes on the last two operands, only that they're some version of ECX, EDX (other than dl/dh).  For example, `monitorx rax, rcx, dx` assembles without complaint.  Using `ebx` or `dl` for the last operand gave "Error: operand type mismatch for 'monitorx'", which is rather unhelpful because it's not the type that's the problem, it's which register it is.  (This is typical of GAS error messages, often less helpful to humans than NASM.)

###### Intel syntax mode,  `.intel_syntax noprefix`

```
objdump -d -Mintel disassembly   |  source
                                 |    .intel_syntax noprefix
0f 01 fa      monitorx           |    monitorx
0f 01 fa      monitorx           |    monitorx rax, ecx, edx
67 0f 01 fa   addr32 monitorx    |    monitorx eax, ecx, edx       # address-size inferred from EAX
67 0f 01 fa   addr32 monitorx    |    addr32 monitorx              # address-size prefix
64 0f 01 fa   fs monitorx        |    fs monitorx rax, ecx, edx    # segment override works, too
```

###### AT&T syntax mode

GAS surprisingly uses the same operand-order as Intel syntax, not reversed like you'd expect for AT&T syntax.  So `%rax` / `%eax` is still first.

GNU Binutils `objdump` chooses to include operands when disassembling into AT&T syntax, unlike with `-Mintel`.

```
 objdump -d -Matt  disassembly (trimmed)   |   source
-------------------------------------------+---------------------------
0f 01 fa      monitorx %rax,%ecx,%edx      | monitorx
0f 01 fa      monitorx %rax,%ecx,%edx      | monitorx %rax, %ecx, %edx
67 0f 01 fa   monitorx %eax,%ecx,%edx      | monitorx %eax, %ecx, %edx       # address-size inferred from EAX
67 0f 01 fa   monitorx %eax,%ecx,%edx      | addr32 monitorx              # address-size prefix
64 0f 01 fa   fs monitorx %rax,%ecx,%edx   | fs monitorx %rax, %ecx, %edx    # segment override works, too
```

---

##### clang 13.0.0 with LLVM's built-in assembler / `llvm-objdump`

`llvm-objdump` gives unhelpful output, not indicating the presence of address-size or segment overrides:

```
       0: 0f 01 fa                      monitorx
       3: 0f 01 fa                      monitorx
       6: 67 0f 01 fa                   monitorx
       a: 67 0f 01 fa                   monitorx
       e: 64 0f 01 fa                   monitorx
```

Similarly, LLVM's built-in assembler doesn't seem to accept operands at all, just saying "invalid operand for instruction".

```
             |  .intel_syntax noprefix
0f 01 fa     |  monitorx
             |  #monitorx rax, ecx, edx     # error
             |  #monitorx eax, ecx, edx     # error
67 0f 01 fa  |  addr32 monitorx             # address-size prefix works
64 0f 01 fa  |  fs monitorx                 # segment override works
```

Same deal in AT&T syntax mode, whether you reverse the operand-list or not.  It doesn't accept `monitorx  %edx, %ecx, %rax` or `monitorx %rax, %ecx, %edx`.

Either way, LLVM does accept `monitorx` and correctly assembles prefixes.
It's only the LLVM-objdump disassembler that fails to show prefixes in any way.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that eax, ecx, and edx are 32 bit registers, but it was being assembled in 64 bit mode. Because the first operand is pointer size, it must be 64 bits. The following code will work on 64 bit programs:

```
push rbx
mov eax, 5844h
mov ecx, 0
mov edx, 0
monitorx rax, rcx, rdx
pop rbx
ret
```

Comment: Fun fact: GNU assembler allows 32 bit address (emits a prefix correctly) but insists on 64 bits for the other operands. That is `monitorx %eax,%rcx,%rdx` assembles. Fun fact #2: operand order is swapped, it is using intel order in at&t mode and vice versa.

Comment: That's odd; AMD's manual explicitly says that ECX and EDX are 32-bit operands.  (For the address operand, they write it as rAX, which I think means it can be EAX or RAX.)  In the pseudocode example, they use `MONITORX EAX, ECX, EDX`, but the 32-bit EAX means that's a 32-bit-mode example.  This is in their vol.3 manual, Nov. 2021 rev 3.33 https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24594.pdf , the latest linked from https://developer.amd.com/resources/developer-guides-manuals/.  (Currently there are no hints or extensions, so ECX must be 0 and EDX is currently ignored.)

Comment: I'd expect `monitorx rax, ecx, edx` to be the normal usage for 64-bit mode.  NASM accepts that in 64-bit mode.